# Clarifications on enthalpy and change in heat energy

Tags: reaction-mechanism, thermodynamics

From my understanding, an exothermic reaction has a negative change in enthalpy meaning that energy is released to the surroundings. However, is it correct to say that during this exothermic process, the enthalpy change of the surroundings is positive? Does this mean that whenever a system has a negative change in enthalpy, another system must have a positive change in enthalpy?

Also, I was wondering what the distinction between change in enthalpy and change in heat energy is. I was told that the change in heat energy has an opposite sign to that of enthalpy during a process. Hence, does heat energy refer to the surroundings??

Comment: Review the guide [How to ask](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Asking FAQs](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to prevent need of clarification, objections, down-voting or closure.

Answer (score 0):

To your first question:

Consider a huge, isolated system $\text{A}$, consisting of two other systems:

- A closed system $\text{B}$,
- A huge closed system $\text{C}$, fully surrounding the system $\text{B}$, acting as a heat bath with constant temperature.

As $\require{cancel} \text{A}$ is isolated, its enthalpy $H_\text{A}$ is constant and  $\text{d}H_\text{A}=0$

If an exothermic reaction occured in $\text{B}$,  and thermodynamic equilibrium is reached in $\ce{A}$, then:

\begin{align}
ΔH_\text{A} &= ΔH_\text{B} + ΔH_\text{C} = 0\\
ΔH_\text{C}&= - ΔH_\text{B}\\
ΔH_\text{B} &\lt 0 \implies ΔH_\text{C} \gt 0
\end{align}

---

For isothermic and isobaric conditions, the enthalpy change of a system is the sum of the heat and nonvolume work (e.g. electricity during battery charging) provided to the system.

By definition:

$$ΔH = ΔU + Δ(pV)$$

For isothermic, isobaric conditions:

\begin{align}
ΔH &= W_\text{volume} + W_\text{nonvolume} + Q  + pΔV\\
ΔH &= \cancel{-pΔV } + W_\text{nonvolume} + Q  + \cancel{pΔV}\\
ΔH &= W_\text{nonvolume} + Q
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The heat of reaction means that, for a closed system operated at constant pressure, the amount of heat that must be added to the system in order to also hold it **at constant temperature** is $Q=\Delta H$.  For an exothermic reaction, heat must be removed from the system to hold it at constant temperature.  So, for a chemically reacting system held at constant temperature and pressure, the heat of reaction is equal to $\Delta H$.